# Can you use the built-in flash in a Canon EOS 450D with a hot shoe GPS geo-tagger?

Tags: canon, flash, canon-450d, gps, popup-flash

As far as I can see, the answer is no, the flash cannot open if anything, is plugged on the hot shoe of a Canon EOS 450D:

[image: Canon EOS 450D]

Can anyone confirm that I wouldn't be able to use something like the Jobo photoGPS and the flash at the same time?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you could use a sync cord (or an optical slave) with a hot shoe adapter to provide another hot shoe for your GPS unit. Since the GPS unit doesn't have camera brand specific models, we can deduct it does not need TTL info, just the basic flash signal. Based on [this thread](http://forums.dpreview.com/forums/readflat.asp?forum=1031&message=32527065&changemode=1) it seems using a sync cord will not disable popup flash on your camera, but you might want to test in shop to be sure.

Comment: Crazy thought... can it be done wirelessly?

Comment: @J. Pablo Fernández Optical slave _is_ a wireless way to do it. You could also use a radio transmitter, but for popup to work, you'd still have to use sync cord to connect it, so you'd just have the transmitter instead of GPS unit dangling from camera.

Comment: I see... thanks for the info... when will they start putting GPSs in DSLRs? (other than Sonny that is)

Comment: I think [my answer](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/7535/where-oh-where-are-the-gps-point-and-shoot-cameras/12082#12082) to similar question about point-and-shoots already covers it - when customers will turn down new models because they lack the feature.

Comment: I certainly wouldn't buy a point and shoot *without* GPS.

Answer (score 2):

There is a sensor in the hotshoe to detect a flashgun; this inhibits the pop-up flash from coming up (or even firing, even if you trick it). You *might* be able to chip off the relevant part of the slide so the camera doesn't detect the hotshoe flash, but I wouldn't personally recommend it.